# How to cache static files when using Vapor framework for Swift

Tags: swift, vapor

There are some css files in Public/css/. I'm accustomed to setting cache rules in the .htaccess for Apache server. How can I make the browswer cache static files when using Vapor?

Comment: Apaches cache settings are not about what the client caches, it is about what apache caches. The browser has it`s own caching logic.

Answer (score 0):

Vapor serves files using its [FileMiddleware](https://github.com/vapor/vapor/blob/master/Sources/Vapor/File/FileMiddleware.swift). You can see that it respects the browser's use of `If-None-Match`, returning `304 Not Modified` as appropriate.

If you need more advanced cache rules, you can roll-your-own file middleware to do this.

The better option, however, is not to use Vapor for static files and instead [deploy it behind nginx](https://vapor.github.io/documentation/deploy/nginx.html) (or Apache), configuring caching in the HTTP server.